# Looking for an implemenentation of binomial tree in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

If anyone can point me into direction where i can find an easy to understand impl. of binomial tree, that would be very helpful. thx

tree should look like in this article: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/high-performance-computing-with-binomial-option-pricing-part-1/

Comment: Is a binomial tree something different than a binary tree?  I've not heard the term binomial tree before.

Comment: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BinomialTree/

Comment: Yes, very different, look at the article in my edited post.

Comment: Edit your profile otherwise diclare your age in profile because you are not 73 year old grandmother

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this example in the past to develop a project that required us to use a binomial tree model, however, this example is in C#.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/binomialtree.aspx